# Handling events in Tapestry layout

Tags: java, events, layout, tapestry

I have a problem in my tapestry project.

Every time I load one page, it triggers onActivate method if is defined in the page in question. But I don't know how to catch that event in my layout template.

If I define a variable in the layout.java, for example:

```
@Property
String a = "foo";
```

And I pick that variable value at the template (layout.tml):

```
<p>${a}</p>
```

Ok, that will print "foo" in the HTML of all pages that use that layout, but If I want to change that value every time that the page reloads, for example defining onActivate in the layout.java.

```
void onActivate(){
    a="bar";
}
```

This method doesn't trigger in the layout.java, only in the child pages when it's defined.
(In the child pages I include the layout like Nathan Q says) How can I refresh the variable value?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find a way to refresh my property value.
And It was very simple:

Instead of declare a property and update that value in the onActivate method, I declare a public method in the layout.java to get that value and make the updating changes there.

```
private String a = "foo";

public String getA(){

    a = "bar";
    return a;
}
```

This way, I can make any changes to the a variable every time the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

I guess layout is a component in this case. Only pages have an activation context, that's why the onActivate() is not fired.

I don't know your exact use case, but:

---

If it's a page specific variable then you can just pass a parameter to your Layout component.

**Layout.java**

```
@Parameter
@Property
private String a;
```

**SomePage.tml**

```
<html t:a="someString" t:type="Layout" ... />
```

**SomePage.java**

```
@Property
private String someString;

...

void onActivate() {
   someString = "something specific for this page";
}
```

---

***OR***

If this variable needs to be set every render and it's not a page specific value, you can just use the SetupRender event of your Layout component.

```
void setupRender() {
   a = ...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for de answer, yes, i do that, I didnt, specified that in my question but yes, I specify <t:type="Layout" ... /> in the page that use the layout and have property in string a, sorry for that

Comment: But I dont pass like the parameter, mmm I don't know if with that will work, but I want to refresh the a value in all pages that use the layout, I have to specific refresh the string parameter in all onActivate methods of the pages?

Comment: In the code sample I gave you, you need a property in the pages and set the value in onActivate(). (Updated code above)
But I'm not sure what your use case is and if this is the best approach...

Comment: If that "a" variable isn't page specific you can just use SetupRender event of your Layout component to set its value.